# Install ROS on Linux Mint 16

Tags: ros, source, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The next instalment in the ever-updating series of installation questions: Is it possible to install ROS on Linux Mint 16 (which is based off Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy)? I've tried using the Raring packages, and (perhaps unsurprisingly) they don't work.

I've also tried installing from source ([using this guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source)), encouraged by some forum posts suggesting that installing from source should work on Ubuntu Saucy. I run into problems when I get to the step that attempts to install the dependencies (`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y`). Specifically, I get `ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies`, followed by the list of dependencies paired with the message `Unsupported OS [mint]`. Is there any way to get around this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118151/install-ros-on-linux-mint-16/) by [hunse](https://answers.ros.org/users/10866/hunse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-01-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For this specific step setting [ROS_OS_OVERRIDE](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE) might help you get further. Basically rosdep doesn't know mint. Just tell it to assume it's ubuntu and hope it works.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @dornhege, that definitely got me going in the right direction! I ended up using the command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=ubuntu:saucy` (note the addition of `--os=ubuntu:saucy`) to do exactly what you suggested.

For other people installing on Linux Mint 16 (or Ubuntu Saucy), there were a few other things I had to do:

1. [Remove shiboken (and libshiboken*)](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/issues/35)
2. Fix my `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` to point to `/usr/lib/libGL.so`.

Also, I did not get the Desktop-Full install working (just Desktop), since gazebo was giving me problems (this might be fixable by following the [Debian suggestions](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Debian)).

---

Originally posted by [hunse](https://answers.ros.org/users/10866/hunse/) with karma: 33 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fercarvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11136/fercarvo/) on 2014-01-23**:
Hey, please can you help me in something?.
I can't install ROS, I have linux mint 16, I've tried install from source but when I try to do the step 1 of the guide $ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential it tells me those package haven't been found. Well, I've already added the packages.ros.org from wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add - but it don't work :( please help me

**Comment by [hunse](https://answers.ros.org/users/10866/hunse/) on 2014-01-23**:
The key is just to verify the repositories, you still have to add the repos themselves to your sources list. Check out step 1.2 in the [Ubuntu install directions](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu), and add the sources for Ubuntu 13.04 Raring.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-24**:
@fercarvo Please open a new question. This seems to be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://naoniloo.blogspot.com/2014/03/ros-hydro-in-linux-mint-installation.html

---

Originally posted by [tushis](https://answers.ros.org/users/14106/tushis/) with karma: 11 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1